# Remember color used in parent, but calculated nested child

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to figure out the right way to remember a color between re-compose, where the color is used in the parent, but calculated in a child.

```
var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Transparent) }

Row(Modifier.height(100.dp)) {
   Box(
      Modifier
         .width(6.dp)
         .fillMaxHeight()
         .background(color)
   )
   Column {
      HorizontalPager(
         count = pages.size,
         state = pagerState
      ) { page ->
         val page = pages[page]
         color = page.color
      }
   }
}
```

However I am running into two issues

1. When the color changes when I page seem to get into an infinite re-compose.
2. The color seems to be a blend of the new page color and the previous page color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having color as state, which is causing your recomposition loop. You could derive the same thing by hoisting your pagerState object and referencing the current page. Something like the following:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
var color = remember(pagerState.currentPage) { pages[pagerState.currentPage].color }

Row(Modifier.height(100.dp)) {
   Box(
      Modifier
         .width(6.dp)
         .fillMaxHeight()
         .background(color)
   )
   Column {
      HorizontalPager(
         count = pages.size,
         state = pagerState
      ) { page ->

      }
   }
}
```